# How to lazy load components to React router dom Route component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, parceljs

I have this:

```
<Router>
  <Route component={MyLazyLoadedComponent} />
</Router>
```

I thought about doing:

```
<Router>
  <Route render={props => {
    import('path/to/component').then(Module => {
      return <Module.default {...props.match.params} />
    })
  }} />
</Router/>
```

But this ain't working since `<Route />` component from the React router Dom isn't async (route is actually rendered **BEFORE** the import). How to achieve this code splitting?

The question actually also relevant for Webpack as well as Parcel bundler.

Comment: You can render dynamic import using [react lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy).

Comment: I have tried this but got: `Error: Cannot find module 'About.04ba37b6.js,../routes/About.jsx,About.04ba37b6.js.map,../routes/About.jsx'`

Comment: How did you setup your react project? Did you use CRA?

Comment: Nope I didn't use it just created it manually

Comment: If you’re setting up Webpack yourself, you’ll probably want to read Webpack’s [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) on code splitting. Your Webpack config should look vaguely like [this](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/ca6e803f5c604d37468b0091d9959269)

Comment: I am using parcel bundler

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
const AsyncComponent = React.lazy(() => import('path/of/component'));

...

 <Route path={`path`} render={props => <AsyncComponent {...props} />} />

...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Tried but it actually doesn't splits the code - there is still one bundle instead of new chunk. Parcel bundler probably doesn't recognise this lazy method from react as something that he should split and track